# Bit datatype to enum type mapping from database to dataset in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, datagridview, dataset

I have a table which has a column `Xyz` and it has `bit` datatype in SQL Server 2008.

I'm getting the values from the table through data adapter and I'm storing it in a `DataSet` and a `DataGridView` will show the contents from the `DataSet`

In the gridview, for column `Xyz`, a check_box with/without tick is displayed but I want to display it as a buy/sell as a text instead of checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle it in 1 of 2 ways.

1) Instead of returning the data as a bit, do the casting in your query to have it return Buy/Sell as a string based on the value. This will only really work well if your grid is read-only. If you need to be able to add/edit data, it would get messy to convert your Buy/Sell back to a bit and enforce that the user could only enter buy/sell. You'd probably want to use method 2 if you need to add/edit data.

e.g. let's say your column name is called BuySell and is of type bit

```
SELECT CASE WHEN BuySell = CAST(0 AS BIT) THEN 'Buy' ELSE 'Sell' AS BuySell FROM TableName
```

2) You will have to turn off "Autogeneratecolumns" on the DataGridView and setup your columns manually. If your grid is read-only, I'd add a text column for your buy/sell column that maps to your bit value. Then in the Cell_Formatting event for the grid, update the value based on the bit. Something like the below:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "buysell")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString() == "1")
            {
                e.Value = "Sell";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Value = "Buy";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = "Buy";
        }
    }
}
```

If your grid needs to be editable, setup a DataTable that represents your Buy/Sell values with a displaymember and valuemember. Bind that as the datasource for a combobox column. Now loading the data will correctly display Buy/Sell in the combobox and for new rows when you select a value from the drop-down it will populate your underlying datasource with the correct bit value.

Comment: can u give sample query for 1st way..?

Comment: Updated answer with a sample query