# how to format bit datatype column in datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a column named `IsApproved` having datatype `bit` in `tblUser` (SQL Server 2008)

Now i need to load record from table to `datagridview` and i did that but in my view this `IsApproved` field is visible as `checkboxes` as

[image]

in my database table row having value `IsApproved=true` then in `datagridview` checkbox is checked and where `IsApproved=false` thien checkbox is unchecked as seen.

So Now I want to show this in particular way that

if `IsApproved=true` then display Approved in place of checked `checkbox` and

if `IsApproved=false` then display  UnApproved instead of unchecked `checkbox`

I got this functionality from [Bit datatype to enum type mapping from database to dataset in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157891/bit-datatype-to-enum-type-mapping-from-database-to-dataset-in-sql-server-2008)
in SQL query but in this statement it give me error that `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IsApproved = CAST(0 AS BIT) THEN 'UnApproved'  ELSE 'Approved'  FROM tblUser
```

I want this solution either in SQL Query or datagridview CellFormatting..

I need help of you people to solve this... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the SQL query fails is because you need to END your CASE statement.

Furthermore the CAST is not required, and you should assign the CASE result to a column name.

This should work:

```
SELECT IsApproved = (CASE WHEN IsApproved = 0 THEN 'UnApproved' ELSE 'Approved' END) FROM tblUser
```

Although using CellFormatting would probably be a better solution in most cases, but this can certainly work.

Comment: this works in SQL i checked just now. will you have any idea about cell formating??