# How to fix datagridview error?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    string age = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn43"].Value.ToString();

    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn43"].Value = (age == "1") ? "Муж" : "Жен";
}
```

When I run program it gives fatal message:

[image]

In database field `gender` is as `integer` type. This value should be added to column name: `dataGridViewTextBoxColumn43`.

Query to database:

public DataTable select(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

```
    return db.GetDataTable("SELECT " +
        "Pacients.id, " +
        "unique_code," +
        "status_pass, " +
        "payment, " +
        "profession," +
        "office_address, " +
        "factory_name, " +
        "factory_edrpou, " +
        "factory_departament," +
        "name, " +
        "secondname, " +
        "lastname, " +
        "datebirth, " +
        "taxcode, " +
        "gender, " +
        "Pacients.created_at, " +
        "file,  " +
        "PacientsOrder.kind_work, " +
        "PacientsOrder.status " +
        "FROM Pacients LEFT JOIN PacientsOrder ON PacientsOrder.pacient_id = Pacients.id LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.pacient_id = Pacients.id ORDER BY Pacients.id DESC");
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? Which line of code gives you error? The code talks about age while your description says about gender but exception is FormatException of  converting number to string while code doesn't have any conversion method used. What am I missing here.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to assign text value to a cell which is bound to a numeric column of datasource. That's when the conversion is failing. Do you have set a specific datatype for the column `dataGridViewTextBoxColumn43`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157891/bit-datatype-to-enum-type-mapping-from-database-to-dataset-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: It has `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` type

Comment: Where I can see accepting type of value?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn43"].ValueType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the folowing, it is obvios, but not clear at once:

The `gender` field is stored in database as `integer` type.

So, when I bind `DataGridView` with existing database table It allocates memory for building table with defination all properties of table, including cell types.

Therefore, when it happends at the first time, the datagridview expects to get integer data type as value, but I modify the value cell to string value and try to overwrite value.

It involkes an fatal error.

Solution was to change all data types that have got `integer` to `string` type.

Thanks for answers, it will be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

If the column `ValueTy‌​pe` is numeric, you can change the number format in the designer to [`Муж;;Жен`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator)

```
dataGridView1.Columns["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn43"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "Муж;;Жен";
```

Comment: On which does type depend?

Comment: @OPV I am not sure what you mean. Zero (0) numbers are formatted to "`Жен`", and positive numbers to "`Муж`". Any numeric signed, unsigned, or floating point type like `int`, `Int64`, `decimal` works

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to add a text value to a column, based on an integer value which is currently in the same column (ie you are switching column value types)?

Please do not do it this way, as it will not work for several reasons.  Apart from your error, the most important being that this event is fired when you set the DataSource of your DataGridView for every row created, but the e.RowIndex is not always the RowIndex of the new row.  For full details read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx).

Normally you would only use RowsAdded when the user has inserted a new row from the interface.

What you should do instead, is to provide this conversion in your SELECT statement that reads the data from the database.  That way you do not need to convert the data when it hits the DataGridView.  So your SELECT needs to be something like:

```
SELECT .... CASE WHEN gender = 1 THEN 'МУЖ' ELSE 'ЖЕН' END AS gender ...
```

Edit

Try changing your SELECT statement so it reads as follows:

```
public DataTable select(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    return db.GetDataTable("SELECT " +
        "Pacients.id, " +
        "unique_code," +
        "status_pass, " +
        "payment, " +
        "profession," +
        "office_address, " +
        "factory_name, " +
        "factory_edrpou, " +
        "factory_departament," +
        "name, " +
        "secondname, " +
        "lastname, " +
        "datebirth, " +
        "taxcode, " +
        "CASE WHEN gender = 1 THEN 'МУЖ' ELSE 'ЖЕН' END AS gender, " +
        "Pacients.created_at, " +
        "file,  " +
        "PacientsOrder.kind_work, " +
        "PacientsOrder.status " +
        "FROM Pacients LEFT JOIN PacientsOrder ON PacientsOrder.pacient_id = Pacients.id LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Transactions.pacient_id = Pacients.id ORDER BY Pacients.id DESC");
}
```

Now you can get rid of the add rows event completely, as the database has done the work for you, before it hits the datagridview.

Comment: I am not understand problem in root

Comment: Please show your code that gets data from the database.

Comment: I do not see it.  I want you to show the query that you run in order to get the data from the database.

Comment: The same trouble, will debug and report soon

Comment: Have you deleted the rows added event? Is your DataGridView using Auto for fields? Or do you set the column types yourself? Have you checked that the query is now returning a string as the gender field?